# Monte Carlo Simulation with Replacement Based On Sum of A Column

Tags: r, simulation, montecarlo

I am trying to simulate an unlikely situation in a videogame using a Monte Carlo simulation. I'm extremely new at coding and thought this would be a fun situation to simulate.

There are 3 targets and they are being attacked 8 times independently. My problem comes with how to deal with the fact that one of the columns cannot be attacked more than 6 times, when there are 8 attacks.

I would like to take any attack aimed at column 2 select one of the other 2 columns at random to attack instead, but **only if column 2 has been attacked 6 times already**.

Here is my attempt to simulate with 5000 repeats, for example.

```
#determine number of repeats
trial <- 5000

#create matrix with a row for each trial
m <- matrix(0, nrow = trial, ncol = 3)

#The first for loop is for each row
#The second for loop runs each attack independently, sampling 1:3 at random, then adding one to that position of the row.
#The function that is called by ifelse() when m[trial, 2] > 6 = TRUE is the issue.

for (trial in 1:trial){
  for (attack in 1:8) {
    target <- sample(1:3, 1)
    m[trial, target] <- m[trial, target] + 1
    ifelse(m[trial, 2] > 6, #determines if the value of column 2 is greater than 6 after each attack
           function(m){
             m[trial, 2] <- m[trial, 2] - 1 #subtract the value from the second column to return it to 6
             newtarget <- sample(c(1,3), 1) #select either column 1 or 3 as a new target at random
             m[trial, newtarget] <- m[trial, newtarget] + 1 #add 1 to indicate the new target has been selected
             m}, #return the matrix after modification
           m) #do nothing if the value of the second column is <= 6
  }
}
```

For example, if I have the matrix below:

```
> matrix(c(2,1,5,7,1,0), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    5    1
[2,]    1    7    0
```

I would like the function to look at the 2nd line of the matrix, subtract 1 from 7, and then add 1 to either column 1 or 3 to create c(2,6,0) or c(1,6,1). **I would like to learn how to do this within the loop, but it could be done afterwards as well.**

I think I am making serious, fundamental error with how to use `function(x)` or `ifelse`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an improved version of your code:

```
set.seed(1)

trial <- 5000

#create matrix with a row for each trial
m <- matrix(0, nrow = trial, ncol = 3)

#The first for loop is for each row
#The second for loop runs each attack independently, sampling 1:3 at random, then adding one to that position of the row.
#The function that is called by ifelse() when m[trial, 2] > 6 = TRUE is the issue.

for (i in 1:trial){
    for (attack in 1:8) {
        target <- sample(1:3, 1)
        m[i, target] <- m[i, target] + 1 
        #determines if the value of column 2 is greater than 6 after each attack
        if(m[i, 2] > 6){ 
            #subtract the value from the second column to return it to 6
            m[i, 2] <- m[i, 2] - 1 
            #select either column 1 or 3 as a new target at random
            newtarget <- sample(c(1,3), 1)
            #add 1 to indicate the new target has been selected
            m[i, newtarget] <- m[i, newtarget] + 1 
            }   
        }   
    }   

# Notice the largest value in column 2 is no greater than 6.
apply(m, 2, max)
```

`set.seed` is used to make the results reproducible (usually just used for testing). The `ifelse` function has a different purpose than the normal if-else control flow. Here's an example:

```
x = runif(100)
ifelse(x < 0.5, 0, x)
```

You'll notice any element in `x` that is less than `0.5` is now zero. I changed your code to have an `if` block. Notice that `m[i, 2] > 6` returns a single `TRUE` or `FALSE` whereas in the small example above, `x < 0.5` a vector of logicals is returned. So `ifelse` can take a vector of logicals, but the `if` block requires there be only a single logical.

You were on the right track with using `function`, but it just isn't necessary in this case. Often, but not always, you'll define a function like this:

```
f = function(x)
    x^2
```

But just returning the value doesn't mean what you want is changed:

```
x = 5
f(5) # 25
x    # still 5
```

For more on this, look up function scope in R.

Lastly, I changed the loop to be `i in 1:trial` instead of `trial in 1:trial`. You probably wouldn't notice any issues in your case, but it is better practice to use a separate variable than that which makes up the range of the loop.

Hope this helps.

P.S. R isn't really known for it's speed when looping. If you want to make things goes faster, you'll typically need to vectorize your code.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the quick response! I certainly have a lot to learn about how to use function and ifelse (and if too!).
Could you describe what my call to `function` was actually doing? Did it not end up being used because I improperly used `ifelse` which sent a vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` when it was expecting a single logical value?

Comment: Sorry, I see you answered my question already. It seems it may have actually being processing what I wanted to, but just because I put m at the end doesn't mean that it was returning m to the loop. I'll do some reading about vectorizing code as well. Thanks again, this is super helpful.

Comment: It's a little odd, but your function was being *returned*, not *evaluated*, when `m[trial, 2] > 6` was `TRUE`. Small example: `ifelse(TRUE, function(x){x}, 0)`, you'll notice the output is just `function(x){x}`. It's not assigned to anything, it's not being evaluated either. You're also returning the whole matrix `m`, which isn't what you want in this case. But since the function is never evaluated, it doesn't matter. Even if it was correct, you would have needed to update your `m` with `m[trial,] = ifelse(...)`. Look up R function scoping, there are plenty of better resources out there.